# 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')'

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have this error:

```
'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')', '; Zone:', 'ProxyZone', '; Task:', 'jasmine.onComplete', '; Value:', TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

This is my `.ts` file:

```
getPillars = async (): Promise<void> => {

        if (localStorage.getItem('pillars')) {
            this.pillars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pillars'));
            return;
        }

        let items = await this.api.send('Categories', 'get', filter ? { filter: filter } : {}).then((res: { data: any[], count: number }) => {
            return res.data.map(el => {
                return { id: el.id, name: el.name, type: 'Categories' }
            });
        });
        localStorage.setItem('pillars', JSON.stringify(items));

        this.pillars = items;
    }
```

And my test file:

```
describe('getPillars()', () => {
    it('Should validate the session success', () => {
        let spy1 = spyOn(apiService, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(of('pillars')));

        component.getPillars();

        expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let items = await this.api.send('Categories', 'get', filter ? { filter: filter } : {}).then((res: { data: any[], count: number }) => {
            return res.data.map(el => {
                return { id: el.id, name: el.name, type: 'Categories' }
            });
        });
```

Here you wait a promise to be returned from send

But later in test you return a promise that resolves into another promise.

You must make it just resolve into some actual value

```
let spy1 = spyOn(apiService, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('pillars'));
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I should resolve the promise?

Comment: have you tried the answer I posted? What is wrong with the provided answer?

Comment: My apologies, I was wrong, your answer is very good

Answer (score 1):

For the test cases, we need to use the catch statement

```
 let data="IND";
  check = false;
  tokenService = false;
  api.getCountriesList(data).catch(() => {});
```

Comment: Thanks man! I forgot the .catch(() => {});

Answer (score 0):

For people with a similar problem that was wasn't solved by the accepted answer:
I was importing the library incorrectly. Check the library you're using to see how they suggest you import it.

```
import openpgp from 'openpgp';
// Throws unhandled promise rejection.
const {notImportant} = await openpgp.readKey({...});
```

```
import * as openpgp from 'openpgp';

// Executes successfully.
const {notImportant} = await openpgp.readKey({...});
```